# Can I pass an event as a parameter to function?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to pass event like parameter of constructor in `Application`?

I have the error

> The event 'SocketIOClient.Client.Message' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data D = new Data();
        Application A = new Application(D.socket.Message);
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public Client socket;

    public Data()
    {
        socket = new Client("https://www.google.com.ua/");
    }
}
public class Application
{
    public Application(EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> Message)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In your below code line `D.socket.Message` has to be a method or property stub that has same signature as the delegate type defined in constructor.

```
Application A = new Application(D.socket.Message);
```